# Foundation 6 Apply scss files to individual pages

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I am new to foundation 6 and I am following the ZURB template using foundation-cli.

I see that a scss file called app.scss is used as the root file that gets compiled to css that is then applied to every html document in src/pages.

I want to be able to create an individual scss file for every page on my site that only gets applied to my page.

How can I do this so that calling foundation watch will only apply a scss file to one particular html document?

Comment: What's the driving force behind this approach? Performance?

Comment: Yes, since my pages are quite distinct very little scss is shared between pages and thus when it is deployed to the web the css files that are generated will be a lot larger than necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend creating different `.scss` files for each page.

For example, if you have 3 distinct pages:

- Home.html
- Page1.html
- Page2.html

Create 3 `.scss` files:

- home.scss
- page1.scss
- page2.scss

Each of these files would import the required Foundation modules, and contain styling for the respective page. There might be some overlap between them and that's ok.

The default Foundation build script `gulpfile.babel.js` will need to be modified slightly. It's only setup to compile `app.scss`. This will need to be changed to compile all `.scss` files in the `/src/assets/scss/` directory.

It's a [simple one-line change](https://gist.github.com/brettdewoody/f35e3cd2b9cb458f89cbf22e29a83808#file-gulpfile-babel-js-L78).

Once the gulpfile is modified it will create 3 separate `.css` files:

- home.css
- page1.css
- page2.css

Next, you'll need to make each page link to the respective CSS file. If you're using static files you can simply link to the respective CSS file. Ex: `home.html` would use `home.css`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
```

If you're using the Zurb Template, which uses Panini to compile pages, you'll need to change the `default.html` layout. This could be accomplished using Panini's `ifpage` to set a conditional CSS file.

```
{{#ifpage 'index'}}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{root}}assets/css/app.css">
{{/ifpage}}

{{#ifpage 'page1'}}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{root}}assets/css/page1.css">
{{/ifpage}}
```

Comment: How do I modify the script? I have 2 different scss files, one called app.scss (generated by the foundation template) and one called test.scss (I created that one). I then have index.html, and test.html. When I run foundation build on the directory the dist/assets folder still only has app.css in it and none of the style in test.scss gets applied to test.html

Comment: You'll need to modify `gulpfile.babel.js`. It's a simple one-line change - https://gist.github.com/brettdewoody/f35e3cd2b9cb458f89cbf22e29a83808#file-gulpfile-babel-js-L78

Comment: Thanks, that fixed one problem. Now multiple css files are generated, however all of my html documents only have links to app.css generated within them, and not their relevant css files. I know I could add them in manually but when developing using the foundation watch command it will be annoying to have to add them back in whenever I make a change. Any fix for this?

Comment: There are a few ways to approach that. One would be to use Panini's [`ifpage`](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/panini.html#ifpage) to conditionally link to different `.css` files depending on the page.

Comment: Second way: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{root}}assets/css/{{page}}.css">`